# Not able to understand the outputs of commands of linux

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, ls, proc

I am a newbie to linux actually I was working with android ndk(new to that too)  I was wondering if someone can explain the meaning of following commands "ls -l /proc/*/fd/" and "ls -l /data/data" .
When I run the following command "ls -l /proc/*/fd/" I got the following output:-

```
lr-x------ root     root              2012-09-07 15:56 4 -> /dev/__properties__ (deleted)
lrwx------ root     root              2012-09-07 15:56 5 -> socket:[257]
lrwx------ root     root              2012-09-07 15:56 6 -> socket:[259]
lrwx------ root     root              2012-09-07 15:56 7 -> socket:[260]
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 2 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 3 -> /dev/log/main
l-wx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 4 -> /dev/log/radio
l-wx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 5 -> /dev/log/events
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 6 -> /system/framework/core.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 7 -> /system/framework/bouncycastle.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 8 -> /dev/__properties__ (deleted)
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 9 -> /dev/binder
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 10 -> /system/framework/ext.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 11 -> /system/framework/framework.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 12 -> /system/framework/android.policy.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 13 -> /system/framework/services.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 14 -> /system/framework/core-junit.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 15 -> /system/framework/framework.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 16 -> /system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 17 -> /system/framework/core.jar
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 18 -> /dev/urandom
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 19 -> /system/framework/framework-res.apk
l-wx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 20 -> /dev/cpuctl/tasks
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 21 -> socket:[616]
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 22 -> pipe:[617]
l-wx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 23 -> pipe:[617]
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 24 -> socket:[620]
l-wx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 25 -> /dev/cpuctl/bg_non_interactive/tasks
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 26 -> pipe:[632]
l-wx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 27 -> pipe:[632]
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 28 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 29 -> /system/app/OpenWnn.apk
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 30 -> /system/app/OpenWnn.apk
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 31 -> /dev/ashmem
lrwx------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 32 -> /dev/ashmem
lr-x------ app_4    app_4             2012-09-07 15:56 33 -> /system/app/OpenWnn.apk
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 2 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 3 -> /dev/log/main
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 4 -> /dev/log/radio
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 5 -> /dev/log/events
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 6 -> /system/framework/core.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 7 -> /system/framework/bouncycastle.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 8 -> /dev/__properties__ (deleted)
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 9 -> /dev/binder
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 10 -> /system/framework/ext.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 11 -> /system/framework/framework.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 12 -> /system/framework/android.policy.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 13 -> /system/framework/services.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 14 -> /system/framework/core-junit.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 15 -> /system/framework/framework.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 16 -> /system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 17 -> /system/framework/core.jar
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 18 -> /dev/urandom
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 19 -> /system/framework/framework-res.apk
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 20 -> /dev/cpuctl/tasks
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 21 -> socket:[621]
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 22 -> pipe:[622]
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 23 -> pipe:[622]
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 24 -> socket:[625]
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 25 -> /dev/cpuctl/bg_non_interactive/tasks
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 26 -> pipe:[638]
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 27 -> pipe:[638]
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 28 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 29 -> /system/app/Phone.apk
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 30 -> /system/app/Phone.apk
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 31 -> /dev/ashmem
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 32 -> /dev/ashmem
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 33 -> /system/app/Phone.apk
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 34 -> /system/app/TelephonyProvider.apk
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 35 -> /system/app/TelephonyProvider.apk
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 36 -> /system/app/TelephonyProvider.apk
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 37 -> /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 38 -> pipe:[730]
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 39 -> pipe:[730]
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 40 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 41 -> socket:[731]
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 42 -> pipe:[750]
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 43 -> pipe:[750]
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 44 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 45 -> pipe:[753]
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 46 -> pipe:[753]
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 47 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 48 -> pipe:[754]
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 49 -> pipe:[754]
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 50 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 51 -> pipe:[756]
l-wx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 52 -> pipe:[756]
lrwx------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 53 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ radio    radio             2012-09-07 15:56 54 -> pipe:[762]
```

and when I ran the "ls -l /data/data" command I got the following output :-

```
drwxr-x--x system   system            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.providers.set
tings
drwxr-x--x system   system            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.settings
drwxr-x--x app_13   app_13            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.launcher
drwxr-x--x app_6    app_6             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.providers.con
tacts
drwxr-x--x system   system            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.providers.sub
scribedfeeds
drwxr-x--x app_0    app_0             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.providers.drm

drwxr-x--x app_14   app_14            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.customlocale
drwxr-x--x app_16   app_16            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.spare_parts
drwxr-x--x app_17   app_17            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.speechrecorde
r
drwxr-x--x app_18   app_18            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.term
drwxr-x--x app_0    app_0             2012-08-10 17:08 com.android.providers.dow
nloads
drwxr-x--x app_19   app_19            2012-08-10 17:08 com.android.deskclock
drwxr-x--x app_28   app_28            2012-08-10 17:08 com.android.email
drwxr-x--x app_0    app_0             2012-08-10 17:08 com.android.providers.med
ia
drwxr-x--x app_4    app_4             2012-08-10 19:57 jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
drwxr-x--x app_6    app_6             2012-08-13 14:54 com.android.providers.use
rdictionary
drwxr-x--x radio    radio             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.providers.tel
ephony
drwxr-x--x app_20   app_20            2012-08-28 19:29 com.android.browser
drwxr-x--x app_21   app_21            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.packageinstal
ler
drwxr-x--x app_22   app_22            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.certinstaller

drwxr-x--x app_23   app_23            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.netspeed
drwxr-x--x system   system            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.systemui
drwxr-x--x app_24   app_24            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.protips
drwxr-x--x app_25   app_25            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.camera
drwxr-x--x app_26   app_26            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.sdksetup
drwxr-x--x app_27   app_27            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.calculator2
drwxr-x--x app_29   app_29            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.development
drwxr-x--x app_1    app_1             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.htmlviewer
drwxr-x--x app_3    app_3             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.defcontainer
drwxr-x--x system   system            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.server.vpn
drwxr-x--x app_5    app_5             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.music
drwxr-x--x app_6    app_6             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.providers.app
lications
drwxr-x--x app_7    app_7             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.wallpaper.liv
epicker
drwxr-x--x app_8    app_8             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.fallback
drwxr-x--x app_9    app_9             2012-08-10 17:07 com.svox.pico
drwxr-x--x app_10   app_10            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.inputmethod.l
atin
drwxr-x--x app_11   app_11            2012-08-10 17:07 android.tts
drwxr-x--x app_12   app_12            2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.soundrecorder

drwxr-x--x app_6    app_6             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.inputmethod.p
inyin
drwxr-x--x app_0    app_0             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.providers.dow
nloads.ui
drwxr-x--x app_0    app_0             2012-08-10 17:07 com.android.gallery
drwxr-x--x app_15   app_15            2012-08-10 17:08 com.android.mms
drwxr-x--x app_34   app_34            2012-09-07 15:55 com.hawkagentmain
drwxr-x--x app_35   app_35            2012-09-07 15:55 com.SampleDumpsys.Activit
y
drwxr-x--x app_30   app_30            2012-09-07 15:55 com.android.gesture.build
er
drwxr-x--x app_31   app_31            2012-09-07 15:55 com.example.android.softk
eyboard
drwxr-x--x app_32   app_32            2012-09-07 15:55 com.example.android.livec
ubes
drwxr-x--x app_33   app_33            2012-09-07 15:55 com.example.android.apis
drwxr-x--x app_6    app_6             2012-09-06 20:47 com.android.contacts
drwxr-x--x app_2    app_2             2012-09-06 20:47 com.android.quicksearchbo
x
drwxr-x--x radio    radio             2012-09-06 20:47 com.android.phone
```

Can anyone tell what these outputs tell?
I will be very thank full to you.

Comment: To the one who has done -1,can u tell why you have done -1 to my question?

Comment: type `man ls` on your command line and read

Comment: @mathematician1975 sir i am running eclipse on window machine and to i run these ls commands in adb shell there is nothing like man ls,i don't have linux machine so i put it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -s /data/data` shows directories and files in /data/data directory with owner name (for instance, app_30), group name (app_30, owner name and group name are equal) and permissions assigned to folders (drwxr-x--x). This directory contains private data of installed android applications.

`/proc/<proc_id>/fd` shows opened descriptors of the process with PID equal to proc_id.

Comment: thanks for the reply sir does the output of "ls -s /data/data " means that that files are currently being read or write?

Comment: No, it simply shows the files and folders under /data/data

Comment: thanks for remarkable info sir .sir is there any way in linux to know which applications are reading or writing a file on disk,i am not concerned with the contents they are reading or writing but the application name that are reading and writing files.

Comment: Use lsof command. It displays all opened files and also shows what PID uses a file.

Comment: Sir does lsof list the files that are currently open at a particular instant?

Comment: Yes, it shows currently opened files. But I do not understand what you mean by 'at a particular instant'

Comment: In the output of lsof,the pids that we get are accessing the files that at that instant by accessing i mean they are reading and writing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16419/discussion-between-chiv-and-yury)

Comment: @Yuy by particular instant i mean when lsof command is fired

Comment: by particular instant i mean when lsof command is fired

Comment: I am not aware of python can u help me in understanding python code

Comment: Sir can u just guide me how to run that python code so that with debugging i can move forward....

Comment: u can get the source code from here http://freecode.com/urls/3eb4107b245fb93dc527da213036984d and extract it through winrar

Comment: sir please have a look at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347201/how-to-know-the-exact-location-where-the-file-is-being-accessed-in-android-ndk

Comment: is there any way to know the location of the file that the application is using?

Answer (score 1):

"ls" means "List the files in the active directory
"-l" means "show me more details to each file (rights, owner, group, creation date, name of the file)
Putting "/proc/fd/" or "/data/data" behind that means: Show the content of this directory instead of the active one

Such an entry: "com.android.deskclock" means that there is a file with that name in the directory
Whereas this "18 -> /dev/urandom" means, that there is a link called "18" in that directory which shows at the file "/dev/urandom"

Comment: thanks for remarkable info sir .sir is there any way in linux to know which applications are reading or writing a file on disk,i am not concerned with the contents they are reading or writing but the application name that are reading and writing files.

Comment: Yup. At first you need the PID of a process, get it via `ps aux` or if you know the process `ps aux | grep PROCESSNAME`, then do `ls -l /proc/PID/fd`. Replace PROCESSNAME and PID.

Comment: how can i know that particular process is reading and writing as ps command outputs all the pids,user,name

Comment: @1554114 how can i know that particular process is reading and writing as ps command outputs all the pids,user,Processname

Comment: To get if for a particular process "PROCESSNAME" you do `ps aux | grep PROCESSNAME`. this will give you a list of PID(s) of processes with the given name. Now you have to check each PID for its open files. Do it with `ls -l /proc/PID/fd`

Comment: is there any way to know the location of the file that the application is using?

Comment: Did you try the commands i listed above? I will execute this for the process `cron`: `ps aux | grep cron` gives the PID **`3244`**; `sudo ls -l /proc/3244/fd` shows four paths here, the fourth is: **`3 -> /var/run/crond.pid
`**. Though the file in use is crond.pid and its location is /var/run/.

Comment: sir when i did ps i got a lot of output but when i did ps aux i didn't get anything and regarding grep,when i ran grep it says not found

Comment: sir i did the following and got the following # ls -l /proc/271/fd
lrwx------ app_28   app_28            2012-09-10 15:33 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ app_28   app_28            2012-09-10 15:33 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ app_28   app_28            2012-09-10 15:33 2 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ app_28   app_28            2012-09-10 15:33 3 -> /dev/log/main
l-wx------ app_28   app_28            2012-09-10 15:33 4 -> /dev/log/radio
l-wx------ app_28   app_28            2012-09-10 15:33 5 -> /dev/log/events

Comment: some more such data was also there

Comment: Aah right, without grep being installed and no chance to get it up running, you have to manually search for the PID of your program, so just run `ps`(with or without parameters, some programs my be hidden without parameters) 
_Or you have luck and you have the program `pgrep` on your system. Try: `pgrep PROCESSNAME`._
And as you pasted above, your program with the PID 271 has three file handles to /dev/null ('null' means 'nothing') and three files: "/dev/log/main, /dev/log/radio, and /dev/log/events"

Comment: user1554114 sir i am able to get the pid through "lsof" but the problem is when we run 'lsof" it shows the same pid with lot of files,how can the procss interact with so much files simuntaneously and we are not able to get the exact path of the file

Comment: sir i am able to get the pid through "lsof" but the problem is when we run 'lsof" it shows the same pid with lot of files,how can the procss interact with so much files simuntaneously and we are not able to get the exact path of the file

Comment: Also `lsof` takes filter arguments: `lsof /usr/sbin/cron` shows all open files of the executeable `cron` (BUT: For executeables running with admin rights, you need to sudo here)

Comment: i did # ls -l /proc/331/fd
ls -l /proc/331/fd
lrwx------ root     root              2012-09-11 13:09 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ root     root              2012-09-11 13:09 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ root     root              2012-09-11 13:09 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ root     root              2012-09-11 13:09 8 -> /dev/__properties__
(deleted)
lrwx------ root     root              2012-09-11 13:09 9 -> socket:[322]
lrwx------ root     root              2012-09-11 13:09 10 -> socket:[410]
Now which file the application is accessing?

Comment: There is three times the same pseudoterminal "0" opened; the file \_\_properties\_\_ is in use, but is marked as deleted. (It can only be used by that programm and will disappear as soon as the program closes); And there are two sockets opened.

Comment: when i did on android device (on which i don't have the root permission) i get->open dir failed permission denied,do i have to get the root permission to run ls -l /proc/pid/fd  ?

Comment: we are also not getting the exact location,how can we map /dev/__properties__ (deleted) to exact location,how to tell user which file is being used

Comment: You need to have the same userrights as the process which the files belong to. (If you want to the the open files of a process started with `sudo ...`, you will have to do `sudo ls ...`)
The exact location is `/dev/__properties__` but the file is already deleted! The only (and last!) chance to see its content is to use the fileDescriptor from proc: `cp /proc/331/fd/8 /your/file/name` and have a look onto the file `/your/file/name`

Comment: sir for every pid in ls -l /proc/pid/fd,that i am running on device i am getting the error of cannot open dir,permission denied, i know they require root privileges,isn't is there any way by which i can know which file are they using

Comment: No, I am sorry, my experience ends here.

Answer (score 0):

The -s switch prints the allocated size of each file listed.

You can also view man pages online: http://man.he.net/