# How to know the exact location where the file is being accessed in Android NDK

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, ls, proc

With "lsof" i can check the list of open files is there any command or any other way by which i can detect where the files the files are being accessed.
The output of "lsof" command is as follows:-

```
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME

init          1        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/1/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          1        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/1/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          1        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/1/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          1        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/1/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init          2        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/2/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          2        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/2/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          2        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/2/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          2        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/2/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init          3        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/3/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          3        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/3/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          3        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/3/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          3        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/3/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init          4        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/4/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          4        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/4/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          4        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/4/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          4        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/4/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init          5        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/5/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          5        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/5/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          5        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/5/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          5        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/5/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init          6        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/6/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          6        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/6/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          6        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/6/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          6        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/6/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init          7        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/7/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          7        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/7/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          7        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/7/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          7        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/7/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init          8        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/8/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          8        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/8/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          8        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/8/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          8        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/8/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init          9        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/9/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)

init          9        ???  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/9/exe (readlink: Permission denied)

init          9        ??? root       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/9/root (readlink: Permission denied)

init          9        ???  FDS                                                   /proc/9/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)

init         10        ???  cwd       ???                ???       ???        ??? /proc/10/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
```

For each pid i am getting three locations like for pid "9" i am getting the following locations:-
"/proc/1/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)","/proc/9/exe","/proc/9/fd/ (opendir: Permission denied)"

Now how can i know which file is exactly being used?
I am a newbie so don't know enough.Any suggestion would be a great help from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Try fuser. http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser
It is used to identify processes using files or sockets.

Comment: sir when i ran "fsuer"  it says "not found"

Comment: i think fuser require root permission i don't have the root permission

Comment: please make sure you ran "fuser" and not "fsuer" as you mentioned in the first comment. If it says "not found" you will have to install it. If it required root permission it would explicitly mention that it requires root permission instead of saying "not found". what distro are you working on?

Comment: Do u know how to install "fuser" in "android ndk"? Is there any other way than "fuser"....i searched but didn't found any link to install fuser

Comment: if there is a way to use lsof in android ndk environment there is a pretty good chance that fuser can also be used in a similar manner. An android-ndk expert might be able to help..

Comment: lsof can be used directly from shell but when i run "fuser" i get "not found"